# cakephp : how to get an array of elements from a web form

Tags: php, cakephp

In my cakephp form I have following code

```
<p> <?php echo $form->input('option[]',array('size'=>13)); ?> </p>
<p> <?php echo $form->input('option[]',array('size'=>13)); ?> </p>
<p> <?php echo $form->input('option[]',array('size'=>13)); ?> </p>
<p> <?php echo $form->input('option[]',array('size'=>13)); ?> </p>
```

I am trying to get values from a set of input text boxes, the number of text boxes can be set by the user, so cant give individual names of each text box, but How can I get values from my controller to insert data to db table

Thank you

Comment: checkout saving hasmany association

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leave the form as it is (and use suggestions from @Wizzard and @Lee), but the best practice is to use an incrementing variable to construct the list. i.e.:

```
for($i=0;$i<$option_number;$i++){
   echo $form->input("MyModel.{$i}.option");
}
```

This way your variable after posting the form will look like:

data[MyModel][0][option] = 'the value'
   data[MyModel](http://book.cakephp.org/view/75/Saving-Your-Data)[option] = 'the value'
   data[MyModel][2][option] = 'the value'
   ... and so on...

In the controller you can access the posted data by:

print_r($this->data);

Take a look [saveAll()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/75/Saving-Your-Data) (search for saveAll in your browser and look for suggested data structure)

Comment: +1 This is, indeed, the correct way to do it. If you want to add the fields before submitting the form, try jQuery append together with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

your input fields are all named the same thing: `option[]`.  This is good.  It causes php to automatically turn them into an array when the request is loaded in.  So you can get them in your CakePHP controller like this:

```
$this->params['form']['option'][0]
$this->params['form']['option'][1]
... and so on ...
```

Comment: print_r($this->params['form']); gives empty values as Array
(
)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure they're in the array $this->params['form'] in the controller.. or $this->data

In the method of your controller, do a var_dump($this); and you'll see where they show up