# html name in php request data

Tags: php, html, cakephp

Hello I need a little help, how I get this same name what I have in html in to php ?

In html I have :

```
<input type="file" name="data[UploadFile][file_upload][]" id="uploadFilefiles">
```

and in php :

```
$this->request->data['UploadFile']['name'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['name'];
```

How can I use these `[]` what I have in html in php ?

Comment: What system is it? What is in "$this" object, I mean what is the class  which contains this PHP code? And why You use so these brackets in HTML? Doesn't seems normal :P

Comment: I use CakePHP framework

Comment: OK. Is this Your code or part of this framework? Both HTML and PHP.

Comment: what u mean ? Yes I use these codes by using CakePHP

Comment: this is you manual html code[] you can't write this you must write into $this->Form->input('UploadFile.file_upload.');

Comment: I add there multiple inputs with javascript, I cant use this.. Multiple uploading files works nicely, but data inserting into database, not working :S

Comment: `$this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['1']['name'];` this works, but I cant to these lines like 100 or more If I need .There is no solution to remove this 1 and put something else in to `[]` ??

Answer (score 0):

in HTML you have

```
<input type="file" name="data[UploadFile][file_upload][]" id="uploadFilefiles">
```

So you get (if you use the method "post" in your form) 
an array in PHP:

```
print_r($_POST['data']['UploadFile']['file_upload']);
```

look here and scroll down:

http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php

Comment: Its not helping me, I need something like this : `$this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['[]']['name'];` , but its not working , its wrong way to do this.

Comment: try to print_r($this->request->data) ... what do you get back?
this construct from you will not work, because [] is a new array in php. 
you can show the data with print_r($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']);

Comment: Ofc I get nothing if I print it, but If I remove in html `[]` and doing this : `print_r($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']); die;` Then I got what I need. BUT I uploading multiple files, and thanks to this I need these `[]`

Comment: look if this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062217/cakephp-how-to-get-an-array-of-elements-from-a-web-form

Comment: the problem with this [] in html is: in php they are after `$data['UploadFile']['file_upload'][x]['name']` (just replace x with the index of your file, zero based)

Comment: Ye , this works `$this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['1']['name'];` but if I have 100 files, then its not nice, and I think its wrong way to do this

Comment: If I put there x then I got `Undefined index: x`